# How to have the drawer push the content instead of going on top of it?

Tags: flutter, material-design

I'm trying to build something similar to the slack app (see screenshot below) where the navigation drawer pushes the screen away instead of going on top.

I've been trying with the [`Drawer`](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/drawer) component without success. I've also looked at [`PageView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) but it seems that the children need to take 100% of the width.

Does someone have an idea of how to implement it?

[image]

Comment: scaffolds openDrawer uses navigator, you could use Single child horizontal scroll view (with disabled scroll physics) with `Scrollable.ensureVisible(context)` to show the menu

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

A similar result can be achieved with a `Stack` and `AnimatedPositioned`

```
class SlidingDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget drawer;
  final Widget child;
  final int swipeSensitivity;
  final double drawerRatio;
  final Color overlayColor;
  final double overlayOpacity;
  final int animationDuration;
  final Curve animationCurve;

  SlidingDrawer({
    Key key,
    @required this.drawer,
    @required this.child,
    this.swipeSensitivity = 25,
    this.drawerRatio = 0.8,
    this.overlayColor = Colors.black,
    this.overlayOpacity = 0.5,
    this.animationDuration = 500,
    this.animationCurve = Curves.ease,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SlidingDrawerState createState() => _SlidingDrawerState();
}

class _SlidingDrawerState extends State<SlidingDrawer> {
  bool _opened = false;

  void open() {
    setState(() {
      _opened = true;
    });
  }

  void close() {
    setState(() {
      _opened = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final drawerWidth = width * widget.drawerRatio;

    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (details) {
        if (details.delta.dx > widget.swipeSensitivity) {
          open();
        } else if (details.delta.dx < -widget.swipeSensitivity) {
          close();
        }
      },
      child: SizedBox(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            AnimatedPositioned(
              width: drawerWidth,
              height: height,
              left: _opened ? 0 : -drawerWidth,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.animationDuration),
              curve: widget.animationCurve,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: widget.drawer,
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedPositioned(
              height: height,
              width: width,
              left: _opened ? drawerWidth : 0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.animationDuration),
              curve: widget.animationCurve,
              child: Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: [
                  widget.child,
                  AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: widget.animationDuration),
                    switchInCurve: widget.animationCurve,
                    switchOutCurve: widget.animationCurve,
                    child: _opened
                        ? GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _opened = false;
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              color: widget.overlayColor.withOpacity(
                                widget.overlayOpacity,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : null,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

As pointed out by @Yadu in the comment

> you could use Single child horizontal scroll view (with disabled scroll physics) with Scrollable.ensureVisible(context) to show the menu

using an horizontal scroll view is working.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _drawerOpened = false;

  final drawerKey = new GlobalKey();
  final mainKey = new GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            key: drawerKey,
            color: Colors.green,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            key: mainKey,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("My Page"),
                leading: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                  onPressed: _toggleDrawer,
                ),
              ),
              body: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _toggleDrawer() {
    setState(() {
      _drawerOpened = !_drawerOpened;
    });
    if (_drawerOpened) {
      Scrollable.ensureVisible(drawerKey.currentContext);
    } else {
      Scrollable.ensureVisible(mainKey.currentContext);
    }
  }
}
```